# INFO: Server startup in 443626 ms for tomcat in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

i have installed eclipse IDE, apache ant 1.8 and tomcat 1.8.2.

When starting the server in eclipse its taking a lot of time and log shows below message in the console.

I am not able to see the configuration page of liferay. How can i fix this?

```
May 26, 2014 3:37:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in 
production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\java
\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:
\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:
\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program 
 Files\java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;.
May 26, 2014 3:37:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9222"]
May 26, 2014 3:37:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 26, 2014 3:37:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1852 ms
May 26, 2014 3:37:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
 May 26, 2014 3:37:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
May 26, 2014 3:37:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\sarika\liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.2\liferay-
 portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3\tomcat-7.0.40\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
Loading jar:file:/C:/sarika/liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.2/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3
/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
Loading jar:file:/C:/sarika/liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.2/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3
/tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
 Loading file:/C:/sarika/liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.2/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3
 /portal-ide.properties
  Loading file:/C:/sarika/liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.2/liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3
  /tomcat-7.0.40/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-developer.properties
  May 26, 2014 3:39:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
  INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
  03:39:37,644 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:71] Determine dialect for 
  HSQL Database Engine 2
  03:39:37,651 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:86] Liferay is configured 
  to use Hypersonic as its database. Do NOT use Hypersonic in production. Hypersonic 
  is an embedded database useful for development and demo'ing purposes. The database 
  settings can be changed in portal-ext.properties.
  03:39:39,187 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:136] Found dialect 
  org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
   03:42:37,085 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][PDFProcessorImpl:235] Liferay is not 
  configured to use ImageMagick. For better quality document and image previews, 
  install ImageMagick and enable it in portal-ext.properties or in the Server 
  Administration control 
  panel at: http://<server>/group/control_panel/manage/-/server/external-services
  Starting Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.2 CE (Paton / Build 6102 / August 2, 
  2013)   03:44:06,242 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:478] Database supports 
  case sensitive    queries
  03:44:12,691 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][ServerDetector:169] Server supports hot 
  deploy
   03:44:12,779 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][PluginPackageUtil:1046] Reading plugin 
   package for the root context
   03:46:07,400 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][AutoDeployDir:144] Auto deploy scanner 
   started for C:\sarika\liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.2\liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3\deploy
    May 26, 2014 3:46:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'Remoting Servlet'
    May 26, 2014 3:47:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\sarika\liferay-portal-tomcat-
    6.1.2\liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3\tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\JspDemo
    May 26, 2014 3:47:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\sarika\liferay-portal-tomcat-     
    6.1.2\liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3\tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\marketplace-portlet
    May 26, 2014 3:47:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\sarika\liferay-portal-tomcat-
    6.1.2\liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3\tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\portal-compat-hook
    May 26, 2014 3:48:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\sarika\liferay-portal-tomcat-
    6.1.2\liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3\tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\resources-importer-web
    May 26, 2014 3:48:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\sarika\liferay-portal-tomcat-
    6.1.2\liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3\tomcat-7.0.40\webapps\welcome-theme
    May 26, 2014 3:48:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9222"]
    May 26, 2014 3:48:34 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    May 26, 2014 3:48:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
   INFO: Server startup in 637937 ms
```

Comment: Try to remove all breakpoints..

Comment: I don't have any break points in my code and I don't have any projects in my workspace. I just want to see the basic configuration page by starting the server but getting this message in console

Answer (score 0):

Log shows that its still using hypersonic database. It is in memory database, so performance depends on CPU utilization on your server and memory allocation. Better to change to MySQL database.

**Change to MySQL database**

Your updated log still has HSQL database connection. You mentioned that you specified MySQL properties. I guess they are not taking into effect. 
Please make sure that your configuration in portal-ext.properties(Please check name of your file, in comment you mentioned file name as portlet-ext.properties, that is wrong) match as below.

Make sure that you keep portal-ext.properties in C:\sarika\liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.2\liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3

```
#
# MySQL
#
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/<your database name here>?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=<your database user name here>
jdbc.default.password=<your database password here>
```

**Increase RAM**

Increasing allocated RAM for liferay tomcat will improve. Below given configuration is just an example. As per availability of RAM on your machine, you may allocate more. But having same value for Xms & Xmx ensures that all memory allocated for tomcat initially saving time on increasing memory gradually.

> -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

If you have liferay tomcat in Windows, Add above configuration to setenv.bat in /bin. In case of Linux, configuration should be in setenv.sh for JAVA_OPTS variable.

Comment: Hi Haris ,I have added the entries in server-open launch configuration-arguments and added the entries in setenv file as well (my OS is windows 8) still facing the same issue.its showing server startup in 1047786 ms i am using mysql connection entries in portlet-ext.properties file and i have my table in sql yog, dont know what is the problem please help me..

Comment: Hello Sarika, Can you attach full log file with latest MySQL connection. This will help me to observe which operation taking longer.

Comment: hi Haris. i ahve added the full log, please check and help me

Comment: It seems your MySQL properties not taking any effect. Please refer "Change to MySQL database" in answer above. from the log that I see above, changing to MySQL and increasing RAM should improve.